# iOS app crashes sometimes when handling HTTPRequest(JSON)

Tags: ios, json, swift, httprequest

For 12 hours, I got 18 times of crashed reports about one HTTPRequest method.

This method is used to load song information from the server, for example, song title, interpret.

The crash reports come from Fabric.io, but I cannot unterstand it very well, it is kind of about NSOperation and thread....

My question is, what did make crash? and how can I improve this function `loadMetadata()`?

This is a screenshot of crash report, why is at **line 0** ??

[image]

This is the code of the HTTPRequest which get JSON data from server

```
func loadMetadata() {

    if self.hasConnectivity() {

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://sites.exampleserver.de/files/playlist/streamdaten_json.txt")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url!)

        let sessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        sessionConfiguration.requestCachePolicy = .ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)

        session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

            if (statusCode == 200) {
                do{
                    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments) as? NSDictionary
                    print(json)
                    var title : String
                    var interpret : String
                    switch (self.channels.channel) {
                    case 0:
                        title = json?.objectForKey("Titel_Live") as! String
                        interpret = json?.objectForKey("Interpret_Live") as! String
                    case 1:
                        title = json?.objectForKey("Titel_InTheMix") as! String
                        interpret = json?.objectForKey("Interpret_InTheMix") as! String

                    default:
                        title = ""
                        interpret = ""
                    }

                    if self.lastTitle != title || self.lastInterpret != interpret || self.lastChannel != self.channels.channel {

                        if title.lengthWithoutWhitespace() < 1 && interpret.lengthWithoutWhitespace() < 1 {
                            self.songTitle = self.channels.currentDefaultArtist
                            self.albumTitle = self.channels.currentDefaultTitle

                        } else {

                            if self.lastTitle != title { // title has changed
                                self.albumTitle = title.lengthWithoutWhitespace() > 1 ? title : self.channels.currentDefaultArtist
                            }
                            if self.lastInterpret != interpret || self.lastChannel != self.channels.channel { // interpret has changed
                                self.songTitle = interpret.lengthWithoutWhitespace() > 1 ? interpret : self.channels.currentDefaultArtist
                            }

                        }
                    }

                    self.lastTitle = title
                    self.lastInterpret = interpret
                    self.lastChannel = self.channels.channel

                    // Test currentInfo
                    self.metaDataHandler.setInfo(artist: self.songTitle, title: self.albumTitle)

                }catch {
                    print("Error with Json: \(error)")
                }
            }
            }.resume()
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not related to your crash, but read the documentation, then figure out why using .AllowFragment is absolute nonsense.

In Swift, an exclamation mark means: "I am 100 percent sure that this thing cannot be nil, and if it ever is nil, then please crash". Apparently the compiler dutifully followed your instructions and crashes from time to time.

The very first hurdle where your app can crash is the "response" parameter, which is *optional*. If it is nil, your app will crash, because that is what you demanded. No surprise that it crashes all over the place. Learn how to handle optionals and change your code accordingly.

Comment: Thank a lot! I have learned about Optional again, and now understood where ist the problem.